# PHP PDO and MYSQL Login code fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is wrong with this code? What is the other alternative? 
 I dont get any error message, but every time i type both combination of username and password it directs me to the login page, even when it is right....

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$query->bindParam(":username"  , $username);
$query->bindParam(":password", $password);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->rowCount();

 if($result>0){
     header("location:admin.php");       
 }else{

     header("location:login.php");
 }
```

Comment: The code looks fine. How is it not working? Dumping a code snippet on us without explaining WHY it's not working is just going to get you downvoted and the question closed. You also have explain what debugging youv'e done. Did you check if you're connecting to mysql ok? Did you check if the query failed? Did you check if $username and $password are properly set? Blah blah blah.

Comment: What is the error message? What is the current behaviour?

Comment: Just as a side note, saving the unhashed password in the database is considered a very serious security vulnerability.

Comment: I dont get any error message, but every time i type both combination of username and password it directs me to the login page, even when it is right....

Comment: While it doesn't look like it will matter in this case, add `exit();` after header redirects, since code can execute afterwards.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha even now a days a hashed password without a salt also considered a very serious security vulnerability

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob: Doesn't make unhashed better.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha obviously , but it makes the hashed one better also :)

Comment: @Wepex - Out of curiousity...can we see the code where you set $username and $password?

Comment: I thought i had outgrown html having switched to it after a number of years. I was code blinded, spend three days looking for this, can you see it? *sigh* `<form name="login" id="login" action="checklogin.php">` I dont have a method!!!!! Made me look like a fool!!!

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to charset errors; try these steps:

1. Save both files (sender.hml and logger.php) as UTF-8.
2. Add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in sender.html.
3. Write `$username = utf8_decode($username);`

To test it, write a `print` before your code:

1. `print "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'"`
2. Copy the SQL and execute it into phpMyAdmin or another SQL Browser.

Good luck!

Comment: I thought i had outgrown html having switched to it after a number of years. I was code blinded, spend three days looking for this, can you see it? sigh `<form name="login" id="login" action="checklogin.php">` I dont have a method!!!!! Made me look like a fool!!!

Comment: The problem was solved? I dont understand your comment. I didnt say to write a method. I'm confusing...

Comment: the problem was solved, eventually, it was more funny than frustrating. The `method` is `method="$_POST"` or `$_GET` for the html form and which PHP was failing to process data from